# Why realloc function is modifying variable 'x' in this code?

Tags: c

I'm studying C and trying to solve exercise 412 of LeetCode.

My problem is, when `x` is `127`, when the line 64 of the code is executed, `x` returns to `124` value and program enters in an infinite loop.

Line 64

```
output = realloc(output, sizeof(char *) * x);
```

My entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **fizzBuzz(int n) {
    int x, temp, x_aux, cont;
    char **output;
    output = NULL;
    for (x = 1; x <= n; x++)
    {
        if (x % 3 == 0)
        {
            if (x % 5 == 0)
            {
                //answer[i] == "FizzBuzz" if i is divisible by 3 and 5.
                output = realloc(output, sizeof(char *) * x);
                output[x-1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 9);
                output[x-1][0] = 'F';
                output[x-1][1] = 'i';
                output[x-1][2] = 'z';
                output[x-1][3] = 'z';
                output[x-1][4] = 'B';
                output[x-1][5] = 'u';
                output[x-1][6] = 'z';
                output[x-1][7] = 'z';
                output[x-1][8] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //answer[i] == "Fizz" if i is divisible by 3.
                output = realloc(output, sizeof(char *) * x);
                output[x-1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
                output[x-1][0] = 'F';
                output[x-1][1] = 'i';
                output[x-1][2] = 'z';
                output[x-1][3] = 'z';
                output[x-1][4] = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (x % 5 == 0)
        {
            //answer[i] == "Buzz" if i is divisible by 5.
            output = realloc(output, sizeof(char *) * x);
            output[x-1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
            output[x-1][0] = 'B';
            output[x-1][1] = 'u';
            output[x-1][2] = 'z';
            output[x-1][3] = 'z';
            output[x-1][4] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //answer[i] == i (as a string) if none of the above conditions are true.
            output = realloc(output, sizeof(char *) * x);
            cont = 1;
            x_aux = x;
            while (x_aux >= 10)
            {
                temp = x_aux % 10;
                output[x-1] = realloc(output[x-1], sizeof(char) * cont);
                output[x-1][cont-1] = temp + '0';
                x_aux = (int)x_aux / 10;
                cont += 1;
            }
            output[x-1] = realloc(output[x-1], sizeof(char) * (cont+1));
            output[x-1][cont-1] = x_aux + '0';
            output[x-1][cont] = 0;
        }
    }
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    char **string;
    int num = 134;
    int m, y;
    string = fizzBuzz(num);

    for (m = 0; m < num; m++)
    {
        for (y = 0; string[m][y] != 0; y++)
            printf("%c", (char)string[m][y]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!!

I know the logic of the solution is not 100% right, but want to know what is happening with `x` changing the value (`127` to `124`).

Comment: `output[x-1] = realloc(output[x-1],sizeof(char)*(cont+1));` passes `output[x-1]` to `realloc`, but, in some execution paths, `output[x-1]`has not been assigned a value at this point, so the value passed to `realloc` is indeterminate.

Comment: Solving exercises on LeetCode won't teach you C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has undefined behavior: in the case of *regular* numbers, neither divisible by 3 nor by 5, you reallocate the array with `output = realloc(output, sizeof(char *) * x)`, which does not initialize `output[x-1]`, and you do not set this pointer to `NULL` before the loop where you construct the number in base 10.  The line

```
output[x-1] = realloc(output[x-1], sizeof(char) * cont);
```

passes an uninitialized pointer to `realloc`, invoking undefined behavior.
Undefined behavior means anything can happen.

You can fix this problem by setting `output[x-1] = NULL;` after this `realloc` call.

Note also these remarks:

- the *regular* numbers are constructed with their digits in reverse order, which the loop in `main` does not correct.
- the array pointed to by `output` should be allocated with a single call to `malloc` or `calloc`, no `realloc` needed
- memory allocation errors should be tested and reported
- allocating copies of the `"Fizz"`, `"Buzz"` and `"FizzBuzz"` strings would be much simpler with `strdup()`.
- allocating strings for the regular numbers is easy with `snprintf` and `strdup`.
- you should output the strings with `printf("%s\n", string[m])`, no nested loop needed.
- the allocated objects should be freed

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **fizzBuzz(int n) {
    char **output = calloc(sizeof(*output), n);
    if (output == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
        if (x % 3 == 0) {
            if (x % 5 == 0) {
                output[x - 1] = strdup("FizzBuzz");
            } else {
                output[x - 1] = strdup("Fizz");
            }
        } else
        if (x % 5 == 0) {
            output[x - 1] = strdup("Buzz");
        } else {
            char buf[20];
            snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", x);
            output[x - 1] = strdup(buf);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

int main(void) {
    int num = 134;
    char **vector = fizzBuzz(num);
    if (vector) {
        for (int m = 0; m < num; m++) {
            printf("%s\n", vector[m]);
            free(vector[m]);
        }
        free(vector);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Once you master the conditional operator, you could use this more compact version:

```
char **fizzBuzz(int n) {
    char **output = calloc(sizeof(*output), n);
    if (output) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
            char buf[32];
            snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", x);
            output[x - 1] = strdup(x % 15 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz" :
                                   x % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz" :
                                   x % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : buf);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```